# My code is deleting the file and removing it from the database records, however, I get an error in the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I'm trying to add a delete image functionality to my website and even though my code deletes the file from the images folder and removes the image record from my database, I get an error in the console and I don't get redirected to my home page. The error is :

```
DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
```

And my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../helpers/db');
var fs = require('fs');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var id = req.body.id;
        var path = req.body.path;
        var author = req.body.author;
        var completePath = 'public/images/uploads/' + path;

        db.query('DELETE FROM image WHERE id = ?', [id], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            if (fs.unlink(completePath)) {
                console.log('Successful');
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.log('Unsuccessful');
            }
        })

    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

My console logs Unsuccessful and it doesn't redirect me to res.redirect('/');

Comment: `fs.unlink` is asynchronous - you can change it to `fs.unlinkSync` - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback

Comment: this is actually a Warning, not a blocking Error. It's normal that the rest of the code is executed, but the async function might not have answered yet, so you get the second alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fs.unlink`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) is an asynchronous function that takes a callback on success. You should use it like this:

```
db.query('DELETE FROM image WHERE id = ?', [id], function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    fs.unlink(completePath,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('unsuccessful');
            return;
        }
        console.log('successful');
        res.redirect('/');
    });
})
```